# Building seperate level 1 and 2 menu in xslt

Tags: xslt, sitecore

I am trying to create a simple menu in Sitecore 6 through xslt.

Currently there is a level 1 navigation, that shows all the menu items on the first level of the site. This works fine. Then i have a level-2 menu, that shows all the sub-items of the current (or parent) level-1 item i am on.

I have it as 2 seperate checks, so they are not linked to each other (because of the styling on the site, level 1 menu items are shown one place, and level 2 items are shown another place).

I am currently using this for level 2 check;

```
<xsl:for-each select="$sc_currentitem/item[sc:fld('In global menu',.) = '1']">
```

But of course this only works, when i am actually on the level 1 item - when i move down to the level 2 item, it no longer works.

Any ideas? It should be pretty darn simple, but i am missing something obvious.

Comment: Provide some input? And some output?

Comment: My suggestion would be to create this kind of things using ascx / .cs because navigation normally can get quiet complicated to solve with XSLT. You are not very specific in what you want to achieve, but this is our normal approach with navigation elements.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your fault is that you use the $sc_currentitem.
You can create a variable or use the existin variable for your home item and iterate through this to show your Menu

something like this `<xsl:for-each select="$home/item[sc:fld('In global menu',.) = '1']">`

than you can compare the $sc_currentitem ID with the iterated item IDs by using a  to know which one is visited at the moment and iterate through this one with something like this `<xsl:for-each select="./item[sc:fld('In global menu',.) = '1']">`

I hope this help.

Best regards,

Phil from netzkern Sitecore Trainingcenter Germany

Answer (score 0):

Are all the 'Sections' of the site based on the same data template? If so you could use something like this (not tested):

```
<xsl:variable name="section" select="'$sc_currentitem/ancestor-or-self::item[@template='templatename']'"/>
```

From here you can use $section/item to get all the second level nav items.